# Would displacement vs time of circular motion be a $\sin/\cos$ curve or parabola?

Tags: kinematics, rotational-dynamics

If you were to graph the displacement from one specific point in a circle of an object rotating, example the boomerangs displacement from the thrower. Would you use a parabola, since in a cos/sin curve it deals with the ratio of lengths at different angles in displacement though we are only looking at the length of displacement from one point.

Comment: Find position w.r.t to centre of circular motion and then shift your coordinate system and then find displacement.

Comment: Displacement is a vector.  How do you graph a vector vs time?  Do you mean distance from thrower vs time?  Or do you mean distance travelled along the path of the boomerang?

Comment: I think the question might addressed by considering arc length, i.e. cumulative displacement or distance traveled. So you would be doing a trigonometric integral where ds is now sqrt(1+(dy/dx)^2)dx

Comment: Note that you use a parabola **only** when you have constant acceleration (in magnitude and direction). Is this the case here?

Answer (score 1):

I assuming that you wish to find the distance from the thrower as a function of time.

Suppose the thrower is at the origin, and the boomerang moves anti-clockwise in a circle of radius a with centre at (0,a) with angular speed $\omega$.  Then the position of the boomerang at time t is (x,y) where
$x = asin(\omega t)$
$y = a(1-cos(\omega t))$.
The distance from the origin is r where
$r^2 = x^2 + y^2$
$= a^2(sin^2(\omega t)+1-2cos(\omega t)+cos^2(\omega t))$
$= 2a^2(1-cos\omega t)$
$= (2asin\frac{\omega t}{2})^2$
$r = |2asin(\frac{1}{2} \omega t)|$.
The graph of r vs t is a sine with amplitude $2a$ and frequency $\frac{1}{2}\omega$.